# Getting build error: Unable to write to path after transition to Universal app

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-universal-app

I have an existing iPhone app (iOS6, ARC, Storyboards, XCode5) that I am trying to convert to Universal.  I did a Duplicate and Transition to iPad, then did a build.  This is what I got:

> Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /Users/sd/Documents/iPhone Apps/SurveyorLevelingI/DerivedData/SurveyorLevelingI/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SurveyorLevelingI.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc

I have moved the DerivedData folder to the project, cleaned the project, shutdown XCode 5, checked the permissions of the DerivedData folder (it's 777) all to no avail.

Any ideas of what to check next?

Comment: Did you try restarting? Sounds stupid but it has fixed issues like this in the past for me.

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard file name appears to have an extra c on the end. This is likely a typo either in code or in the Project/Build Settings file.

MainStoryboard.storyboardc

Should probably be:

MainStoryboard.storyboard

Comment: Right, I saw that, but figured it was added by the compiler... I did a search for it, but nothing showed up... how do I remove it?

Comment: @spokane-dude I would try searching the build settings for Main.. There might be a broken reference in your storyboard file. I'd right click on the view controllers in the file and look for any yellow or red indicators.

Comment: I found this:  
    **Your storyboard is compiled to nib files and packaged into a storyboardc file within your app bundle.**  I'm going to check the permissions of all the folders and see what's going on...